# android: location code sample crashes

Tags: android

I have downloaded the sample code for location from
https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/

I am trying to run it to see but it always crashes after app launch.
I have checked the manifest but I didnt find anything wrong. Has any one faced similar problem with the above sample code.

Here is the crash log.

> 03-19 12:06:05.456: D/AndroidRuntime(9185): Shutting down VM 03-19
>   12:06:05.456: W/dalvikvm(9185): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x414e62a0) 03-19 12:06:05.503:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-19 12:06:05.503:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9185): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.radioactiveyak.location_best_practices/com.radioactiveyak.location_best_practices.UI.PlaceActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.radioactiveyak.location_best_practices.UI.PlaceActivity 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2021)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-19 12:06:05.503:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-19 12:06:05.503:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-19 12:06:05.503:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9185): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.radioactiveyak.location_best_practices.UI.PlaceActivity 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 03-19
>   12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2012)
>   03-19 12:06:05.503: E/AndroidRuntime(9185):   ... 11 more

Comment: did you forgot to download/copy `PlaceActivity` in the `UI` package?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.radioactiveyak.location_best_practices.UI.PlaceActivity

Comment: @Tushar : No, I have dowloaded the entire code using SVN, and yes i have PlaceActivity intact and also referenced in the manifest "<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name=".UI.PlaceActivity">"

Comment: Do you have edited your Google Places API key?

Comment: @gpasci : Yes,and also added the backup_manager_key

Answer (score 0):

Did you try project -> Clean? Do you have to add the permision in manifest of location?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning and building several times, but no luck , here are the list of permission I have used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I solved it by going to: Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export Tab
And then ive put the checkmark on the "android-support-v4.jar"